# React Router rendering pages on Footer

Tags: reactjs, react-router, create-react-app, react-router-dom

React Router is loading my pages all the way at the bottom of the page, on the Footer every time I redirect. Any suggestions?

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <Router>
    <Nav />
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
      <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
      <Route exact path='/register' component={Register} />
      <Route exact path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
      <Route exact path='/subscriptions' component={Subscriptions} />
      <Route exact path='/newPost' component={NewPost} />
    </Switch>
    <Footer />
  </Router>
</Provider>
```

Comment: What does your provider component do?  Its not good to wrap your router as a child component.  Its better to have them be top level components so you can then pass down route information.

Comment: @jgetner It is necessary for Redux

Comment: I'd need to see more of the code to be able to help on this one. There might be something odd in the css, but I really don't know yet.